# Go + Fleet 1.17.66. Debug tool does not appear on Windows, but working on Ubuntu (vmware)

Tags: go, debugging, fleet

Parameters:

Fleet version: build 1.17.66
OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64)
Cores(2): Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4216 CPU @ 2.10GHz 2.10 GHz
Ubuntu 22.04 via vmware on Windows 10.

I am testing Fleet ver. 1.17.66 with Golang .
I read manual from this [weblink](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/debug-go-code.html) 
and debug mode is not working for me.
I am able to run the program(using Run button), but while running it in debug mode I'm getting the following output:
“API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:59141”

[image]

And it seem like nothing happens from there on.

However, I ran the same on Ubuntu(running inside vmware) the debug works correctly.

**Any help would be really appreciated in fixing this and finding out what could be wrong.**

PS. I have sent the issue to the tool authors but they redirected me to ask for help from community on SO.

Comment: It seems like it is working fine. Try adding a breakpoint and then run it in debug and see if the program stops at the debug breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks. The debug output hide a breakpoint, the screenshot is not informative.